# Save data in observable (ionic 4)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, injectable

I would like to save user data after login in an observable and retrieve the data later in the profile page.
I have a simple **user.service.ts**

```
  @Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private _user: BehaviorSubject<IRegisterUser> = new BehaviorSubject<IRegisterUser>(null);
  public user$: Observable<IRegisterUser> = this._user.asObservable();

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  public setUser(user) {
    this._user.next(user)
  }
```

which successfully updates the behavior subject.

Later I try to have access of the observable in **profile.page.ts**

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public userSrv: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.userSrv.user$.subscribe(resp=> {
     console.log(resp)
   })

  }

}
```

But my response is **null**

I have put the user.service.ts in the providers of app.module and profile.module but I probably miss something else.

Comment: Did you push a new `user` to the observable? If not you will receive the default value `null`. Now if you were to push a new user to the observable after the subscription, they will be reflected in the `profile.page`.

Comment: What I did is `this._user.asObservable();` and add the value to the behavior subject. Where should I push the value to the observable?

Comment: When the user is logged in I call the method `setUser(user)` and I successfully update the behavior subject. I saw it on debug mode. The problem is that my subscription in `profile.page.ts` doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have put the user.service.ts in the providers of app.module and profile.module but I probably miss something else.

There is a problem, remove `UserService` from `profile.module` providers. Now `profile.module` have his own provider of `UserService` instead of using global provider.